# UnicodeDecodeError With CSV File

Tags: python, csv, text, readfile

When I import a csv file, python throws the following error:

```
  File "/Users/sethkillian/Documents/Python/metar/metar.py", line 31, in get_AirportInfo
    for line in airports:

  File "/Users/sethkillian/anaconda/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 358: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Using Microsoft Excel, I saved the file as a UTF-8 CSV file.

I also tried putting `.decode('UTF-8')` on the end, but it won't accept a string.

Here's my original code:

```
def get_AirportInfo():
    airports = open('airport_codes.csv','r')
    for line in airports:
        print(line.strip().split(','))
```

Any thoughts? I looked in the file and I couldn't find any special characters that should trip it.

Comment: Try airports = open("'airport_codes.csv'", "r", encoding="utf-8")

Comment: Can you post the file by any chance? I usually run through and try decoding each value in each column to see which ones are causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 `str` has no attribute `decode`, but you can read the file as binary, and decode it line by line

```
with open('airport_codes.csv', 'rb') as fp:

for line in fp:
    print(line.decode('utf-8').strip().split(','))
```

If you want to make it Python2 compatible, use the `codecs` module, although in Python3 built-in `open` has argument for `encoding`:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('airport_codes.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8'):

for line in fp:
    print(line.strip().split(','))
```

These solutions likely will work, as `0xc3` might be valid in `utf-8` if another byte follows.